# SQL Server replication max server name length

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

## Question

Does SQL Server have a max server name limitation for SQL Server Replication with publishers or subscribers?

## Background:

My coworker is worried about going above 15 characters for  a server name. We are currently looking to go to the cloud where it would be really helpful to break the 15 character limit, but my coworker is hesitant about doing so, stating that at least in times past SQL Server replication didn't handle it very well. I've looked as much as I can online and see no current limitations, but unfortunately that doesn't mean there isn't one.

## What I know:

I know that you can create a host with a longer name then 15 characters. I also know that in our case, Active Directory truncates the name and appends random characters to the end, but that it stores the actual value as part of the DNS property.

I know that SQL Server @@servername can be longer then 15 characters.

## Details:

We have an environment where we are migrating to SQL Server 2019 Enterprise from SQL Server 2014 Enterprise, and so have a mix of both. We replicate from SQL Server 2019 to both SQL Server 2019 to SQL Server 2014 Enterprise. If it matters we are running Windows 2012 R2 for SQL Server 2014 and Windows 2019 Standard for the SQL Server 2019 hosts. We have a central distributor that is running SQL Server 2019 Enterprise.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give.

Comment: It seems to me that a server name is a sysname as datatype so it is equivalent to nvarchar(128) not null...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/naming-conventions-for-computer-domain-site-ou

Comment: The potential problem with server name length isn't really 
on SQL Server's side, but really a matter of whether anything in your infrastructure requires legacy NetBIOS name resolution. I think the question you need to ask is "How can I tell if I am dependent on NetBIOS names?" Which would be better answered on a different site on it Stack network.

Comment: We don't have any netbios limitations, and I know that the server name is a sysname, but I really need to know if there are hidden limitations to help my coworker know one way or the other. Thanks for the reminder though that I need to watch out for NetBIOS.